# Draw route or make custom slider on google_map Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, gps, slider

I have a document in Firestore that has a data of latitude and longitude such as:

```
[{"latitude": 36.xxxx, "longitude": 120.xxx}, {"latitude": 35.xxxx, "longitude": 121.xxx}, {"latitude": 35.xxxx, "longitude": 122.xxx}...]
```

with this data I want to create a map and route(or slider) that connects coordinates, and there should also be a marker that can be dragged over the line. (Motion of default slider).

My Question is as follows:

1) Is there a way I can make a custom slider that looks like the picture below?

2) Is there a way I can draw a route in a map using polylines in firebase cloud function and then upload the data?

The view I want to make is the picture below. If there is any other recommendation feel free to say. Thank you

[image: nike run club]